# Ubuntu Machine boots into BusyBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, busybox

My ubuntu VM was working fine. Now when I boot up it boots into BusyBox.
I have run the Unbuntu boot tool with no luck.
Here is the log from the boot tool.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/17567076/

How can I get my VM to boot into the ubuntu again?